# hiding address bar on iphone's safari doesnt work

Tags: iphone, html, safari, iphone-standalone-web-app

I want my site not to display the address bar when viewed in iPhone's safari. From my research this metatag should do the trick, if only targeting iphone devices:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
```

it doesnt seem to do the trick when I'm testing on 4S.

also tried

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

Does anything else need to be done?

Answer (score 2):

The `apple-mobile-web-app-*` meta tags you refer to in your question only apply when a user adds your web application to their home screen, after which they can click on the icon and it appears to be a native app (even though it is not).

As long as your application is being accessed inside Safari on the device, the Safari chrome will appear.